# iPhone asks me to enter sandbox Apple ID password constantly

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store

I created a number of sandbox Apple IDs for testing with In-App purchase. Logged out of the App Store on my iPhone, and logged in on those accounts.

Now the behaviour I'm seeing is that my phone constantly wants me to enter the password for these Apple IDs. It doesn't stop.

I've tried pressing "OK" until they go away, I've tried entering the password, I've tried signing into these accounts on the App Store, then signing out. I've tried restarting my phone.

Short of 'Restore to factory settings', is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Same issue here. I am not signed into the sandbox account in the store settings. I do not have any pre-release apps installed. I even bought a new iPhone (although restored from iCloud) and I still get that sandbox login alert.

Comment: Having the same issue.  Did you guys find a solution to this?